# Grep a path containing an environment variable and using it

Tags: unix, grep, tcsh

I'm using tcsh, and I'm trying to grep a path from a file with several ID, I'm doing:

> grep I241149 $ENV_CASTRO/ALL_CMD_LINES.BAK | grep -o \$"ENV_CASTRO.*.asm"

that gets me:

$ENV_CASTRO/central/WS678/test_do_all.asm

but if I try

> cp `grep I241149 $ENV_CASTRO/ALL_CMD_LINES.BAK | grep -o \$"ENV_CASTRO.*.asm"` .

it prompts

cp: cannot stat `$ENV_CASTRO/central/WS678/test_do_all.asm': No such file or directory

How do I tell tcsh that the output of grep contains a $ that means it is an environment  variable and is not plain text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` is your friend ....

```
eval cp `grep I241149 $ENV_CASTRO/ALL_CMD_LINES.BAK | grep -o \$"ENV_CASTRO.*.asm"` .
```

I don't have the time to create files to test this.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the output of the grep command is not being evaluated by the shell, and so variable substitution is not happening.

One way to solve this would be to execute the desired command within another shell, for example,

```
sh -c "cp `grep I241149 $ENV_CASTRO/ALL_CMD_LINES.BAK | grep -o '$ENV_CASTRO.*.asm'` ."
```